# get top n values for each row in a matrix with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose you have the following matrix

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([[10,50,30],[60,20,40],[15,30,90]])
```

You can obtain the index for the highest value in each row as follows

```
r,c = np.unravel_index(a.argmax(axis=1)+ np.arange(0,a.shape[1]*a.shape[0],a.shape[1]), a.shape)
print(a[r[0],c[0]])
print(a[r[1],c[1]])
print(a[r[2],c[2]])
```

How can you get the indices for the top `n` values for each row?

Comment: Sort with the row axis, and then the first n columns

Answer (score 0):

Sort the rows and select the last n columns:

```
In [315]: a = np.array([[10,50,30],[60,20,40],[15,30,90]])
In [316]: a
Out[316]: 
array([[10, 50, 30],
       [60, 20, 40],
       [15, 30, 90]])
In [317]: np.sort(a, axis=1)
Out[317]: 
array([[10, 30, 50],
       [20, 40, 60],
       [15, 30, 90]])
In [319]: np.sort(a, axis=1)[:,-2:]
Out[319]: 
array([[30, 50],
       [40, 60],
       [30, 90]])
```

Your max expression could be simplified to:

```
In [324]: a.argmax(axis=1)+ np.arange(0,a.shape[1]*a.shape[0],a.shape[1])
Out[324]: array([1, 3, 8])
In [326]: a.flat[_]
Out[326]: array([50, 60, 90])
```

Comment: I wasnt clear enough in my question. I need to find the indices of the top n values. I have updated my question.

Comment: have you tried `argsort` in the same way?

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed!

Comment: Can you update your answer so I can check it out?

Answer (score 0):

You should able to just use `np.argpartition` and set `axis=1`:

```py
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([
              [10,50,30],
              [60,20,40],
              [15,30,90]
              ])
n = 2
indices = np.argpartition(a, -n, axis=1)[:, -n:]
print(indices)
print('\n', np.sort(indices))
```

```
[[2 1]
 [2 0]
 [1 2]]

 [[1 2]
 [0 2]
 [1 2]]
```